# presto/aws athena - select latest version of a record

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I've got a order events table that consists few entries per order as it gets fullfilled. Some orders get cancelled or refunded. I'm trying to select latest versions of all the order for which the latest version has status 'OrderConfirmed' I assumed I would use the following SQL but AWS Athena complains that Column 'latest_order_update.latest_update' cannot be resolved. Any clues?

```
WITH latest_order_update AS (
  SELECT orderevent_order.unique_id, MAX(orderevent_order.event_time) AS latest_update
  FROM orderevent_order
  GROUP BY orderevent_order.unique_id)
SELECT orderevent_order.unique_id
FROM orderevent_order
WHERE orderevent_order.event_time = latest_order_update.latest_update AND orderevent_order.header_event_name = 'OrderConfirmed'
LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could rewrite it with `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
 SELECT oo.unique_id,
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY unique_id ORDER BY event_time DESC) rn
  FROM orderevent_order oo
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Or refer to cte in `FROM/JOIN`/subquery:

```
WITH latest_order_update AS (
  SELECT orderevent_order.unique_id, 
     MAX(orderevent_order.event_time) AS latest_update
  FROM orderevent_order
  GROUP BY orderevent_order.unique_id)
SELECT orderevent_order.unique_id
FROM orderevent_order
WHERE orderevent_order.event_time IN (SELECT l.latest_update 
                                      FROM latest_order_update l
                                      WHERE orderevent_order.unique_id 
                                         = l.unique_id)           
  AND orderevent_order.header_event_name = 'OrderConfirmed'
LIMIT 10;
```

Join:

```
WITH latest_order_update AS (
  SELECT orderevent_order.unique_id, 
     MAX(orderevent_order.event_time) AS latest_update
  FROM orderevent_order
  GROUP BY orderevent_order.unique_id)
SELECT orderevent_order.unique_id
FROM orderevent_order
JOIN latest_order_update
  ON orderevent_order.event_time = latest_order_update.latest_update
 AND orderevent_order.unique_id = latest_order_update.unique_id
WHERE orderevent_order.header_event_name = 'OrderConfirmed'
LIMIT 10;
```